# generate unique hash keys of url

Tags: c++, boost, hash

i want to generate unique hash keys of an url.
atm im using boost hash

```
  std::size_t seed = 0;
  boost::hash_combine(seed, host);
  boost::hash_combine(seed, path);
  boost::hash_combine(seed, query); 
  boost::hash_combine(seed, fragment);
```

but the hash keys are very often duplicate... :(

```
http://www.finanzen.de/geldanlage-boerse.html  9223372036854775807                  
http://www.finanzen.de/geldanlage-china.html   9223372036854775807
```

does someone have a SIMPLE alternative?

Comment: what are the types of `host`, `path` and others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an error in that code. The hash values are different with this dummy example:

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    size_t seed = 0;
    std::string s1("www.finanzen.de");
    std::string s2("geldanlage-boerse.html");
    std::string s3("geldanlage-china.html");

    boost::hash_combine(seed, s1);
    boost::hash_combine(seed, s2);
    fprintf(stdout, "%016lx\n", seed);

    seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(seed, s1);
    boost::hash_combine(seed, s3);
    fprintf(stdout, "%016lx\n", seed);
    return 0;
}
```

Now if your `host`, `path`, etc... are `char*`s, and you're reusing those pointers, then the result you're getting makes sens. There is no overload of `hash_value` for `char*`. So the only thing that will go into the computation is the pointer value itself (exactly how is not defined). (See the very bottom of the [hash reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine).)

Other point: this `9223372036854775807` value is quite special. Its hex representation is:

```
0x7fffffffffffffff
```

So you probably have a conversion/overflow problem somewhere that is not visible in what you posted.

Comment: hmm the problem is thast i often get 9223372036854775807 i put the original key in the mysql database  defined by bigint(20). ??

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples of input producing this hash?  Also, as mentioned before, the types of the variables you are hashing.  (Best would be a simple example along the lines of what Mat gave.)

Comment: hey, the problem was with bigint.. now im useing unsigned bigint and its working! THX

Answer (score 0):

Try with some md5 functions implemented for C